# How do I associate colors with a a specific user in a datatable

Tags: vb.net, colors, dataset

I'm fairly new to using Visual Basic. And I have never worked with databases/datatables before now.

On my datatable (I hope that's the correct word) I have two columns that I want to store color values. I changed the data type to "System.Drawing.Color".

However it would appear I cannot simply type in the string (e.g: "Color.Black") to add it to the database. And when using an update SQL query and make it look for color values on the form, it wants to convert them to string.

Is it possible to store color values like this in this way or do I have use another method?

Comment: [What color do you want that database?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rJvde.gif)

Answer (score 0):

All colors are presented by a string on either "Color.Black" or "#000000", so the only thing you can do is convert it to a string when you put into DataTable, then convert it back to a color when you retrieve it from the Datatable